# Javascript function define

Tags: javascript

I'm currently new to javascript programming. And I have a question about function.
When I tried to modify html DOM. I could either use function or no function.

The function one is as below:

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>

<p id="demo">This is a demonstration.</p>

<script>
function myFunction() { 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello";
}
```

And the no function one is here:

```
<p id="demo">This is a demonstration.</p>
<button type="button" onclick= "getElementById('demo').innerHTML= 'Hello'">Click Me!             </button>
```

My question is :Why there it is document.getElementById()... in function case ,  but getElementById() in non function case? 
What's the document. for?

Thanks!!

Comment: @Bijan no no no no no no no no no no do not link W3Schools. Use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What's the document. for?

To access the [`document` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document), where the [`getElementById` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) resides.

> Why there it is document.getElementById()... in function case , but getElementById() in non function case?

It should always be there. In the *inline event handler* case, it [can be omitted](http://jibbering.com/faq/names/event_handler.html) however (which is considered bad practise, though).